# Emoji in Mysql with PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, emoji, aruba

I have this table
[image: My table]

When I try to insert "" in the field "it is not saved correctly ... why?

[image: Insert to]

[image: Error]

Output of SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%set%":

character_set_client utf8
character_set_connection utf8mb4
character_set_database utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results utf8
character_set_server latin1
character_set_system utf8

I don't have access to the console because I use external hosting (Aruba)

sorry for any grammatical errors but i don't speak english well

Comment: Could just be an issue with PHPMyAdmin's display of the field value in that UI. Have you tried querying it from a PHP script configured with [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin has been able to handle UTF8 data for a very long time, including the emoji characters, so this is not a problem with how phpMyAdmin handles the data.

Which phpMyAdmin, PHP, and MySQL/MariaDB versions are you using?

On the main page of phpMyAdmin, what is the value selected from the "Server connection collation" dropdown"? This value has to be something that would support showing the emoji character set. My first guess is that you've got some other collation selected there that's causing the trouble.

[image: phpMyAdmin home page]

Your query and column type works fine on my installation with phpMyAdmin 5.0.2, MariaDB 10.3, and PHP 7.4.